# Asking to keep (or buy) specific keyboard I use at work pending my departure

Tags: professionalism, ergonomics, exit-planning

I am leaving the company I currently work for in two days.  I currently use a hhkb pro 2 and really enjoy it.  I inherited it from another colleague who asked for the company to purchase it for him while he was on-boarding.  He left it at the office since "he wouldn't feel right taking something  had paid for".  That made sense to me and I definitely don't feel right stealing company property.

However, the keyboard is quite specialized (no labels on the keys, unusual layout, small number of overall keys) and I know that it will probably end up sitting in storage, unused for an extended period.

**What would be a professional way to approach my manager to ask if I could purchase the keyboard from the company?**

Comment: Why doesn't it have labels on the keys? Quick google search seems to indicate that normally the keys are labeled. Just curious.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it doesn't have labels.  I suppose the idea is that if you're touch typing it shouldn't matter and the keyboard does have a nice clean look. Oh! and if you are using an alt keyboard layout (dvorak, etc.) it won't make a difference .  Here's the model in question: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008GXT6SK/ref=psdc_12879431_t1_B008GXQWOG

Comment: Why not buy one and save the drama?

Comment: it's a $300 keyboard, I'd rather save the $$ if I could.

Answer (score 13):

> What would be a professional way to approach my manager to ask if I
>   could purchase the keyboard from the company?

"*Hello, would it be okay if I took this keyboard with me?  I doubt anyone else would use it once I leave as it is a highly specialized product, and I am one of the few that is proficient with it*".

If the answer is yes, be sure to get confirmation via email and **forward this email to your private email account**.

Another option would be to *offer to buy* it from the company and a reduced, used, rate.  I would do this **after** you ask for it, you just might get it for free.

Comment: Talk to your IT department, and show them a picture of it with the blank keys. They'll want that nightmare of a keyboard out of there very quickly. IT departments hates dealing with non-standard stuff like this.